# Android camera supported picture sizes

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to retrieve the available camera image sizes, so I able to adjust the camera to my preferred image resolution.

To retrieve the Android camera size I've used the following code:

```
camera=Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
    Log.i("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " +sizes.get(i));         
}
```

This gives me the following output, which I am not sure how to translate into a size.

```
"Supported size: android.hardware.Camera$Size@65d4c50"
"Supported size: android.hardware.Camera$Size@65d4a70"
"Supported size: android.hardware.Camera$Size@3fe4e00"
"Supported size: android.hardware.Camera$Size@3fe4cd0"
"Supported size: android.hardware.Camera$Size@18f5600"
"Supported size: android.hardware.Camera$Size@13f7860"
```

If anyone could help me understand the output it would help me a lot, thanks!

Edit: I ended up solving my problem by doing the following:

```
camera=Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Camera.Size result = null;
    for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
        result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
        Log.i("PictureSize", "Supported Size. Width: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height); 
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getSupportedPictureSizes()` returns a `List` of `Camera.Size` objects. `Camera.Size` has `height` and `width` data members that tell you the height and width of the supported picture size.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview) that uses the related `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` to find the preview size with the largest area that is smaller than the `SurfaceView`'s size.

Comment: Thanks solved my problem now. Somehow I had missed that I would get Camera.Size objects by calling getSupportedPictureSizes(). The sample project was great.

Comment: CommonsWare, in your project you're not setting the picture size - is it even necessary to set the picture size I wonder? Because it's giving me serious trouble supporting a wide range of different devices and keeping the preview and picture size in sync and not letting them get too small due to the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Zainodis: "in your project you're not setting the picture size" -- that particular sample doesn't take a picture. It only sets up the preview. "is it even necessary to set the picture size I wonder?" -- it is possible that there's a default, but I always set one. "Because it's giving me serious trouble supporting a wide range of different devices and keeping the preview and picture size in sync and not letting them get too small due to the aspect ratio" -- I feel your pain, as I deal with some of that in my CWAC-Camera helper library.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for answering :) I was afraid there won't be an easy solution. Seems camera-handling is (one of) the holy grail(s) of Android xD.

Answer (score 5):

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++) {
    Log.i("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " +sizes.get(i).width + "height : " + sizes.get(i).height);     
}
```

You have to take height and width from one size object

Comment: I couldn't quite get it to work that way. I ended up doing the following instead: Declared a camera size variable then used it to hold each object and got the width/height from that. Not quite sure why I am not able to implement it like you suggested.

Comment: @krishnabhadra    I wonder whether the first element of the List sizes ( sizes.get(0) ), is the best picture size the Camera given? or just a random good picture size Camera given?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example of how to search for the size that is aprroaching your max size (1024 * 768) for example.

```
                List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
                //searches for good picture quality
                Camera.Size bestDimens = null;
                for(Camera.Size dimens : sizes){
                    if(dimens.width  <= 1024 && dimens.height <= 768){
                        if (bestDimens == null || (dimens.width > bestDimens.width && dimens.height > bestDimens.height)) {
                            bestDimens = dimens;
                        }
                    }
                }
                parameters.setPictureSize(bestDimens.width, bestDimens.height);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. Since the method `params.getSupportedPictureSizes()` returns a list of type `Camera.Size`, it was easy to do this:

```
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();

        //searches for good picture quality
        for(Camera.Size dimens : sizes){
            if(dimens.width  <= 1024 && dimens.height <= 768){
                Debug.WriteLine("Width: " + dimens.width + " Height: " + dimens.height);
                return dimens;
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Width: " + sizes.get(sizes.size()-1).width + " Height: " + sizes.get(sizes.size()-1).height);
        //returns the smallest camera size if worst comes to worst
        return p.getSupportedPictureSizes().get(sizes.size()-1);
```

You can get a `List<Camera.Size>` and traverse it like any other list. the `Camera.Size` object has a `width` and `height` property.

Declaring your `List`this way might be better than casting each element of the list to type `Camera.Size` inside of a loop.

On my devices, if I look at `sizes.get(0)`, it will have the highest resolution while `sizes.get( sizes.size()-1 )` has the lowest. I'm not sure if this is true across all devices, however. Anyone have insight on that?

Comment: On my Samsung Galaxy Note II, the smallest size is index 0, going up. So it is not the same across all devices.

Comment: Yeah Samsung phones are difficult to work with when it comes to the camera. There are other issues too, such as images being flipped around (without exif interfaces). I've seen people try to detect if the device is a Samsung device and run functions based on that. What a pain, am I right?

Comment: Yes, very sad all this. Especially as writing drivers should be part of the OS.