# Webcam supported picture sizes

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am attempting to retrieve the available picture-size resolutions supported by my webcam; using the OpenCV library. I have tried working with similar Android question/answers but to no avail. (e.g. [Android camera supported picture sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993652/android-camera-supported-picture-sizes)). Here is my code:

```
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.core.Size;

public class MyCameraCaptureClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, OpenCV");
    System.out.println("This program will display the webcam's supported sizes");

    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java248"); //load .dll for the jar

    VideoCapture vidCap0 = new VideoCapture(0);

    if (vidCap0.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("Camera found, and it works so far...");

        for (Size aSize : vidCap0.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            System.out.println("Doesn't print this at all");
            System.out.println("Height:" + aSize.height + "Width:" + aSize.width);
        }
    }
    vidCap0.release();
    }
}
```

And the stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.getSupportedPreviewSizes_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.getSupportedPreviewSizes(VideoCapture.java:478)
at webcam.MyCameraCaptureClass.main(MyCameraCaptureClass.java:19)
```

All help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Eugene Evdokimov - just for you :))

Comment: It seems this is a bug in OpenCV, which has been fixed recently: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3387

Comment: I checked another link and it says they should release the fix with v2.4.9. Now I can rest, many thanks :)

Comment: Too bad for the 500rep bounty :)

Comment: Well, I guess if you use the trunk version, you should be able to circumvent the issue..

Comment: @scap3y If this is their only issue I would recommend fixing the particular bug as I described below before just grabbing the trunk if this is production code. Too many changes to test otherwise.

Comment: @Koffy Did you end up fixing the bug for your code?

Comment: @Matthew No, I figured it safest to wait for the next OpenCV download :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in the comments this is a reported bug that has been listed as corrected for 2.4.9:

- http://code.opencv.org/issues/3387
- http://code.opencv.org/issues/3477

That said, the project is open source, and looking at the code change that corrects this, it is a simple fix. You could just implement that bug fix and build it yourself to use until 2.4.9 is released. The associated revision is here:

- In the VideoCapture.cpp file: [REVISION 5f88e2b4](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/5f88e2b496f320ca86389316d13d7b4e571a4568/diff/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/VideoCapture.cpp)

Lines 332->335:

**Replace:**

```
return env->NewStringUTF(u.name);
```

**With:**

```
// VideoCapture::get can return 0.0 or -1.0 if it doesn't support
// CV_CAP_PROP_SUPPORTED_PREVIEW_SIZES_STRING
if (u.prop != 0.0 && u.prop != -1.0)
    return env->NewStringUTF(u.name);
```