# What is the difference between getSupportedPreviewSizes and getSupportedPictureSizes in Android?

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I am diving into Camera based app development and am looking into capturing a list of resolutions a phone's camera can support.

Is getSupportPreview or PictureSizes the best way to go? If so, what is the difference between them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993652/android-camera-supported-picture-sizes refer to this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should most probably use both. Preview size is the size in which the camera is displaying what it is seeing on your screen. So the data that is coming through the cameras' sensor is being displayed at say 1920x1080. But the picture size is that size that image will be captured in. So you maybe be showing the image to the user as they are taking it at 1920x1080 but the image that is captured could be at 4160x3120 or whatever it may be.